# NestJS/TypeORM. TypeORM doesn't update entity in DB, uses old cached entity instead

Tags: mysql, nestjs, uuid, typeorm

I am experiencing immense difficulties all day trying to save an entity into a MySQL database. I am using NestJS and TypeORM.

**teacher.entity.ts**

```
import { BeforeInsert, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { bcryptConstants } from 'src/bcrypt/bcrypt.constants';

@Entity({'name': 'teacher'})

export class Teacher {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(bcryptConstants.saltRounds);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
        this.password = hash;
    }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SubjectsController } from './subjects/subjects.controller';
import { SubjectService } from './subjects/subject/subject.service'
import { TeacherModule } from './teacher/teacher.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [ TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'test',
    entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true
  }), TeacherModule, AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController, SubjectsController],
  providers: [AppService, SubjectService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's the error:

```
+10767ms
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `teacher`(`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["babbb","babbb","$2b$10$CMyzTJU6g1gJX2eO8Ulleez.LKo1XTCHvVKeUFKJS2FF9bwXivNR."]
query: COMMIT
+120008ms
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `teacher`(`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["babbb","babbb","$2b$10$XU8QNxCRL4Ole2OxWkInruLogt0/e/SAfJoAhw.dBbad3MBb5D.iS"]
query failed: INSERT INTO `teacher`(`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["babbb","babbb","$2b$10$XU8QNxCRL4Ole2OxWkInruLogt0/e/SAfJoAhw.dBbad3MBb5D.iS"]

error: Error: Duplicate entry 'babbb' for key 'teacher.IDX_76fd0cda3fc6719d3109237c72'
{
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry 'babbb' for key 'teacher.IDX_76fd0cda3fc6719d3109237c72'"
}
query: ROLLBACK
[Nest] 5360   - 03/06/2021, 9:59:03 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Duplicate entry 'babbb' for key 'teacher.IDX_76fd0cda3fc6719d3109237c72' +192ms
```

The entity actually gets saved in the database but it takes a whole minute for NestJS to finish this task and return a response. I am using Angular which waits for this response in order to redirect the user to a login page after registering as a teacher. I only get an error with status 500 a minute after sending a post request to create a teacher in the database.

**mysql table**

```
id  username    email   password
1   user12  user    $2b$10$kYZ3F2Hv2MkuvQJIBUsK5Ogq4PHQPLiOBp1t9x3.psOwL984/KTQe
4   babbb   babbb   $2b$10$CMyzTJU6g1gJX2eO8Ulleez.LKo1XTCHvVKeUFKJS2FF9bwXivNR.
```

I've inserted 2 entries but for some reason, it skipped saving on ID 2 and 3.

I tried using "uuid" as an ID like this:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uiid")
id: string;
```

But still it gives me an error that the generated uuid string is too long to be saved in an integer value, when I've clearly defined the column as a string.

Any suggestions are welcome!

**UPDATE**

TypeORM adds a unique index to my columns "username" and "email" even though I haven't specified it in "@Column()".

```
query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'typeorm_metadata'
query: ALTER TABLE `teacher` CHANGE `username` `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL
query: ALTER TABLE `teacher` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_76fd0cda3fc6719d3109237c72` (`username`)
query: ALTER TABLE `teacher` CHANGE `email` `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
query: ALTER TABLE `teacher` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_00634394dce7677d531749ed8e` (`email`)
query: COMMIT
```

Even if I use "@Column({ unique: false})", it will still add unique index to them. I don't have this problem with other tables, just this one.

**SECOND UPDATE**

Alright, I know what the problem now is for sure. TypeORM doesn't synchronize my entity properly, more specifically the "teacher" one. When I add new columns to "teacher" table, it updates properly. When I remove the columns "email", "password", "username" from my code, they are still in the table, there's no way I can alter these columns. I don't know if it is related to some cache problem. My synchronization "synchronize: true" is on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify to your `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` to generate a **UUID** and not <s>UIID</s> or Integer as you tried.

```js
# Not like this
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uiid")
id: string;

# Like this
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
id: string;
```

Here is how your entity need to be wrote specifying the **UUID** column type.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'teacher' })
export class Teacher {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(bcryptConstants.saltRounds);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
        this.password = hash;
    }
}
```

About the delay when saving, Bcrypt is hashing your passwords and it takes a long time usually.

Comment: Yes, I mistyped "uuid" with "uiid" but I am using an autogenerated number for my ids now. I figured out that the problem is related to TypeORM making columns like "username" and "email" unique, when I haven't specified them anywhere to be. So when I try to post entities with the same "username" or "email", it is throwing the Duplicate error.

Comment: Glad I solved your problem ! About your problem, TypeORM doesn't make any field primary or unique by default with `Column()` field, you need to specify `unique: true` or `primary: true` in column options.

Answer (score 2):

Simply clear your dist folder

```
rm -rf dist
```

Then run

```
yarn build // or npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know NestJS is supposed to use TypeScript and then in order for the app to run on NodeJS, everything is translated to JavaScript and saved in the "dist" file, including entities written in TypeScript and TypeORM.

Because I changed the columns of my "teacher" entity many times and I later changed TypeORM's option to "synchronize: true", TypeORM used old files for entities from "dist" instead of using the updated ones that I have written in TypeScript.

So when you have TypeORM and "synchronize: true", TypeORM will create the tables in your database for you, but in my case it was building them using old/cached files from the "dist" directory.

**How to fix it**

Try to provide these options to TypeORM when importing it to your module

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
     autoLoadEntities: true,
     synchronize: true,
     ...
}
```

**OR**

Delete your current dist folder and then run this command `npm run build` so it can newly create the dist folder again and possibly remove old files.

Comment: I advise you never to use the synchronize option of TypeORM, generate your migrations on database changes to avoid bugs.